# Indefinite while loop eventhough I have given a valid condition

Tags: java

I have written a code that calculates the percentage of marks obtained by a student. The while loop runs indefinitely even though i have given a valid condition. for eg: say I enter the number of subjects =2, the while loops doesn't just stop with 2 inputs for marks. can someone please help.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

class student{
    int n;
    int m[];
    float percentage;

    public void calculate(){
        int total=m[0]+m[1];

        for(int j=2;j<n;j++)
        {
            total= total+m[j];
        }
        percentage = total/n;           
        System.out.println("Your percentage equals = "+percentage);
    }    
}

public class PercentageCalc{    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{          
        student s1=new student();
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the total number of subjects ");
        s1.n=br.read();
        int a=s1.n-1;
        s1.m=new int[a];
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Please enter your marks one after another ");
        while(i<=a)
        {       
            s1.m[i]=br.read();
            i++;                
        }           
        s1.calculate();
    }       
}
```

Comment: indefinite?? that means there is still hope it might end - just hang in there tight!!

Comment: I get it. U r smart. But if could just help, it would be much better:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `br.read()` reads a `char` and not an `int`, so the ascii 2 is equal to 50 ... so it is not infinite ... just feels so :)

Furthermore, I assume that you are hitting 'Enter' after every input, so I suggest you use a readLine instead, try the below code for main :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

student s1=new student();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("enter the total number of subjects ");
try{
s1.n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{}
//int a=s1.n-1; // By doing this, you make the array one shorter than you seem to need, so you will not be able to enter the data for the last subject.
int a=s1.n; //this should have enough space to store marks for all subjects.
s1.m=new int[a];
int i=0;
System.out.println("Please enter your marks one after another ");
while(i<a)
{
    try{
    s1.m[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    { System.out.println("Bad value entered, please enter again "); // additional check for invalid numbers, just in case ;) 
    continue;}
    i++;
}
s1.calculate();
}
```